# Permission denied issue in a java program

Tags: java, unix, permissions

I have a unix system user `teamcity` which untars a tar inside a directory in unix.

The tar contains a jar file and other directories containing configuration files. It also has a log directory and a file `/log/abc.log`.

Since `teamcity` is running the tar command, all the files and directories in the resultant extract have `teamcity` as owner and group.

I have another system user which runs the jar file viz. `abcuser`.

When I run the jar file as `abcuser`, and when program tries to access `/log/abc.log` file I get below exception:

```
Nested:java.io.FileNotFoundException: log/abc.log (Permission denied)
```

What is the solution for this ? I can not make any of the user `teamcity` and `abcuser` as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options here.

## 1. Allow all local users to read /log/abc.log

```
sudo chmod o+r /log/abc.log
```

## 2. Put teamcity and abcuser in a common group.

```
sudo groupadd loggingGroup
sudo usermod -g loggingGroup abcuser
sudo usermod -g loggingGroup teamcity
```

Allow only members of the group to access /log/abc.log

```
sudo chmod g+r /log/abc.log
```

Comment: Option 2 requires a system reboot. Is there a way to achieve it without system reboot ?

Comment: Create a new login session (logout, login) should be ok on system level. For your applications this probably means  a restart...See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208617/how-to-update-user-group-settings-of-a-running-process